# List of objects loose property values

Tags: arraylist, properties

I am a relatively newbie to Java programming, and therefore apologize in advance if this is suppose to be simple, but I cannot figure it out.

I have the following code:

Article is a class as follows:

public class Article {

```
private String title;
private String author;
private List<String> tags;
```

my Main code that is intended to create a Arraylist of Articles is as follows:

```
    List<Article> myArticles = new ArrayList<Article>();
    List<String> myTags = new ArrayList<String>();

    String title;
    String author;

    title = "Pillars of the Earth";
    author = "Ken Follet";
    myTags.add("fiction");
    myTags.add("historical");
    myTags.add("best seller");

    myArticles.add(new Article(title, author, myTags));

    System.out.println(myArticles.get(0).toString());

    title = "Programming with java";
    author = "Louw Pieters";
    myTags.clear();
    System.out.println("myTags size : "+myTags.size());
    myTags.add("java");
    myTags.add("programming");
    myTags.add("best seller");

    myArticles.add(new Article(title, author, myTags));

    for (Article myItem : myArticles) {
        System.out.println(myItem.toString());
    }
```

**I get the following output:**

Article [title=Pillars of the Earth, author=Ken Follet, tags=[fiction, historical, best seller]]

myTags size : 0

Article [title=Pillars of the Earth, author=Ken Follet, tags=[**java, programming, best seller**]]

Article [title=Programming with java, author=Louw Pieters, tags=[java, programming, best seller]]

Why did it change the tags of the first Article object that was 'stored' in a List. I thought it would be 'protected' in the list?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private List<String> tags;
```

defines tags as a field for an instance of the Article class. It means that when tags receive a value the object for it receives the value will hold a reference on that value as long as it is alive (not garbage collected).

So even though you have a

```
List<Article> myArticles = new ArrayList<Article>();
```

It does not mean that the tags elements will be protected when an instance of Article is put in the List. The List also holds reference of each element that is added to it.

So when you used this instruction:

```
myTags.clear();
```

You actualy emptied the tags that were associated with the first article
When you created a second article and used the same reference variable myTags in its constructor: you associated myTags with the second article as well, that's why after changing the tags, both articles are now displaying the same list of tags

If you want to avoid this, instead of

```
myTags.clear();
```

use

```
myTags = new ArrayList<>();
```

And it will work as expected because now you associate a differente instance to the second article, the first article holding reference to the first instance.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your suggestion and now it is working fine.

Comment: @Louw Pieters, glad it helped :)